# iTunes purchase in Objective-C

Tags: in-app-purchase, itunes

Is there any way to purchase a song on iTunes programmatically using the user iTunes credentials (given for granted the user safely stores his account information inside the app)? In other words is it possible to automatise the in-app-purchase process if the user grants his permission?

Comment: I certainly hope not! I would like to be required to authorize any purchase an application thinks I should make (even if the application thinks I've explicitly told it to make the purchase) _thankyouverymuch_. To put it a different way… "What could possibly go wrong?!"